# Custom heading and subject email notification for custom order status in WooCommerce 4

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status, email-notifications

i have created the custom status shipped but unfortunately mail are send default of processing when we change order status to shipped not the one we define in fuction shipped_status_custom_notification , can you please help me

```
/**
     * Add custom status to order list
*/
    add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_post_status', 10 );
    function register_custom_post_status() {
        register_post_status( 'wc-shipped', array(
            'label'                     => _x( 'Shipped', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
            'public'                    => true,
            'exclude_from_search'       => false,
            'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
            'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
            'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Shipped <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Shipped <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' )
        ) );

}

/**
 * Add custom status to order page drop down
 */
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'custom_wc_order_statuses' );
function custom_wc_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $order_statuses['wc-shipped'] = _x( 'Shipped', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
    return $order_statuses;
}
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'shipped_status_custom_notification', 10, 4);
function shipped_status_custom_notification( $order_id, $from_status, $to_status, $order ) {
        if( $order->has_status( 'shipped' )) {

        // Getting all WC_emails objects
        $email_notifications = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();

        // Customizing Heading and subject In the WC_email processing Order object
        $email_notifications['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->heading = __('Your Order shipped','woocommerce');
        $email_notifications['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->subject = 'Your {site_title} order shipped receipt from {order_date}';

        // Sending the customized email
        $email_notifications['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
  }

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-shipped', array( WC(), 'send_transactional_email' ), 10, 1 );


add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'filter_woocommerce_email_actions' );
function filter_woocommerce_email_actions( $actions ){
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-shipped';
    return $actions;
}
```

Comment: Any feed back on the answer below will be appreciated please.

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce has changed a lot through all plugin updates since 2018, so to get an email notification for your custom order status with custom heading and subject use the following instead:

```
// Register (add) a new post status
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_post_status', 10 );
function register_custom_post_status() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-shipped', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Shipped', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Shipped <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Shipped <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );

}

// Enable this custom status status for WooCommerce order (and sort them)
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'custom_wc_order_statuses' );
function custom_wc_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $sorted_order_statuses = [];

    foreach( $order_statuses as $key => $label ) {
        $sorted_order_statuses[$key] = $order_statuses[$key];
        if( 'wc-processing' === $key ){
            $sorted_order_statuses['wc-shipped'] = _x( 'Shipped', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }
    return $sorted_order_statuses;
}

// Adding this custom status to admin order list bulk dropdown
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order', 20, 1 );
function custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order( $actions ) {
    $actions['mark_shipped'] = __( 'Mark Waiting in tree', 'woocommerce' );
    return $actions;
}

// Enable the action
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'filter_woocommerce_email_actions' );
function filter_woocommerce_email_actions( $actions ){
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-shipped';
    return $actions;
}

// Send Customer Processing Order email notification when order status get changed from "tree" to "processing"
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'shipped_status_custom_notification', 10, 4);
function shipped_status_custom_notification( $order_id, $from_status, $to_status, $order ) {
    if(  'shipped' === $to_status ) {
        // The email notification type
        $email_key   = 'WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order';

        // Get specific WC_emails object
        $email_obj = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()[$email_key];

        // Sending the customized email
        $email_obj->trigger( $order_id );
    }
}

// Customize email heading for this custom status email notification
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_heading_customer_processing_order', 'email_heading_customer_shipped_order', 10, 2 );
function email_heading_customer_shipped_order( $heading, $order ){
    if( $order->has_status( 'shipped' ) ) {
        $email_key   = 'WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'; // The email notification type
        $email_obj   = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()[$email_key]; // Get specific WC_emails object
        $heading_txt = __('Your Order Shipped','woocommerce'); // New heading text

        return $email_obj->format_string( $heading_txt );
    }
    return $heading;
}

// Customize email subject for this custom status email notification
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_customer_processing_order', 'email_subject_customer_shipped_order', 10, 2 );
function email_subject_customer_shipped_order( $subject, $order ){
    if( $order->has_status( 'shipped' ) ) {
        $email_key   = 'WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'; // The email notification type
        $email_obj   = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()[$email_key]; // Get specific WC_emails object
        $subject_txt = sprintf( __('Your %s order shipped receipt from %s', 'woocommerce'), '{site_title}', '{order_date}' ); // New subject text

        return $email_obj->format_string( $subject_txt );
    }
    return $subject;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and Works.