# Add a new order status that Send an email notification in WooCommerce 4+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status, email-notifications

I would like to add a new order status and email notification to my site in conjunction with this order status. I tried this code:

```php
// register a custom post status 'awaiting-delivery' for Orders
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_post_status', 20 );
function register_custom_post_status() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-awaiting-delivery', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Kargoya Verildi', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Kargoya Verildi <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Kargoya Verildi <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );
}

// Adding custom status 'awaiting-delivery' to order edit pages dropdown
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'custom_wc_order_statuses', 20, 1 );
function custom_wc_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $order_statuses['wc-awaiting-delivery'] = _x( 'Kargoya Verildi', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
    return $order_statuses;
}

// Adding custom status 'awaiting-delivery' to admin order list bulk dropdown
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order', 20, 1 );
function custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order( $actions ) {
    $actions['mark_awaiting-delivery'] = __( 'Kargoya Verildi', 'woocommerce' );
    return $actions;
}

// Adding action for 'awaiting-delivery'
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'custom_email_actions', 20, 1 );
function custom_email_actions( $action ) {
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-awaiting-delivery';
    return $actions;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-awaiting-delivery', array( WC(), 'send_transactional_email' ), 10, 1 );

// Sending an email notification when order get 'awaiting-delivery' status
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_awaiting-delivery', 'backorder_status_custom_notification', 20, 2);
function backorder_status_custom_notification( $order_id, $order ) {
    // HERE below your settings
    $heading   = __('Kargoya Verildi','woocommerce');
    $subject   = '[{site_title}] Siparişiniz Kargoya Verildi ({order_number}) - {order_date}';

    // Getting all WC_emails objects
    $mailer = WC()->mailer()->get_emails();

    // Customizing Heading and subject In the WC_email processing Order object
    $mailer['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->heading = $heading;
    $mailer['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->subject = $subject;

    // Sending the customized email
    $mailer['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
}
```

But the code doesn't send e-mail. How can I fix this situation? I tried a few other codes. But none of them worked.

NOTE: I am typing this code in the function.php file, do I need to write it somewhere different?

Comment: I believe this answers your question: [Custom heading and subject email notification for custom order status in WooCommerce 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63170962/custom-heading-and-subject-email-notification-for-custom-order-status-in-woocomm/63173282#63173282)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on [this answer code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48616541/add-custom-order-status-and-send-email-on-status-change-in-woocommerce/48617516#48617516) and [this unaccepted answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63170962/custom-heading-and-subject-email-notification-for-custom-order-status-in-woocomm/63173282#63173282), Here is the revisited code, that will add a custom status to WooCommerce orders and will trigger a customized email notification for this custom status:

```php
// register a custom post status 'awaiting-delivery' for Orders
add_action( 'init', 'register_custom_post_status', 20 );
function register_custom_post_status() {
    register_post_status( 'wc-awaiting-delivery', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Kargoya Verildi', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public'                    => true,
        'exclude_from_search'       => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Kargoya Verildi <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Kargoya Verildi <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'woocommerce' )
    ) );
}

// Adding custom status 'awaiting-delivery' to order edit pages dropdown
add_filter( 'wc_order_statuses', 'custom_wc_order_statuses' );
function custom_wc_order_statuses( $order_statuses ) {
    $order_statuses['wc-awaiting-delivery'] = _x( 'Kargoya Verildi', 'Order status', 'woocommerce' );
    return $order_statuses;
}

// Adding custom status 'awaiting-delivery' to admin order list bulk dropdown
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order', 20, 1 );
function custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order( $actions ) {
    $actions['mark_awaiting-delivery'] = __( 'Kargoya Verildi', 'woocommerce' );
    return $actions;
}

// Adding action for 'awaiting-delivery'
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'custom_email_actions', 20, 1 );
function custom_email_actions( $actions ) {
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-awaiting-delivery';
    return $actions;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-awaiting-delivery', array( WC(), 'send_transactional_email' ), 10, 1 );

// Sending an email notification when order get 'awaiting-delivery' status
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_awaiting-delivery', 'awaiting_delivery_order_status_email_notification', 20, 2);
function awaiting_delivery_order_status_email_notification( $order_id, $order ) {
    // HERE below your settings
    $heading   = __('Kargoya Verildi','woocommerce');
    $subject   = '[{site_title}] Siparişiniz Kargoya Verildi ({order_number}) - {order_date}';

        // The email notification type
        $email_key   = 'WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order';

        // Get specific WC_emails object
        $email_obj = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()[$email_key];

        // Sending the customized email
        $email_obj->trigger( $order_id );
}

// Customize email heading for this custom status email notification
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_heading_customer_processing_order', 'email_heading_customer_awaiting_delivery_order', 10, 2 );
function email_heading_customer_awaiting_delivery_order( $heading, $order ){
    if( $order->has_status( 'awaiting-delivery' ) ) {
        $email_key   = 'WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'; // The email notification type
        $email_obj   = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()[$email_key]; // Get specific WC_emails object
        $heading_txt = __('Kargoya Verildi','woocommerce'); // New heading text

        return $email_obj->format_string( $heading_txt );
    }
    return $heading;
}

// Customize email subject for this custom status email notification
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_customer_processing_order', 'email_subject_customer_awaiting_delivery_order', 10, 2 );
function email_subject_customer_awaiting_delivery_order( $subject, $order ){
    if( $order->has_status( 'awaiting-delivery' ) ) {
        $email_key   = 'WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'; // The email notification type
        $email_obj   = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()[$email_key]; // Get specific WC_emails object
        $subject_txt = sprintf( __('[%s] Siparişiniz Kargoya Verildi (%s) - %s', 'woocommerce'), '{site_title}', '{order_number}', '{order_date}' ); // New subject text

        return $email_obj->format_string( $subject_txt );
    }
    return $subject;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.