# WooCommerce: Add Custom order statuses with custom email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

Using [Add a new order status that Send an email notification in WooCommerce 4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64607271/add-a-new-order-status-that-send-an-email-notification-in-woocommerce-4/64608630#64608630) answer code, I have been able to get an email notification for ONE custom status however cannot get my head around how I would go about being able to send the email notification for BOTH custom statuses.

See below the example codes & The code I have tried for multiple custom status email notification. I have also included my FULL code which shows the entire process of creating the multiple statuses.

Would love some help on this quick fix!

Also, As for the email BODY - Is there any possibility of changing what the Processing Order content says through this code without having to create a new email template?

**WORKING - Single Custom Status email notification "Shipped"**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'filter_woocommerce_email_actions' );
function filter_woocommerce_email_actions( $actions ){
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-shipped';
    return $actions;
}
// Send Customer Processing Order email notification when order status get changed from "tree" to "processing"
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'shipped_status_custom_notification', 10, 4);
function shipped_status_custom_notification( $order_id, $from_status, $to_status, $order ) {
    if(  'shipped' === $to_status ) {
        // The email notification type
        $email_key   = 'WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order';
        // Get specific WC_emails object
        $email_obj = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()[$email_key];
        // Sending the customized email
        $email_obj->trigger( $order_id );
    }
}
// Customize email heading for this custom status email notification
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_heading_customer_processing_order', 'email_heading_customer_shipped_order', 10, 2 );
function email_heading_customer_shipped_order( $heading, $order ){
    if( $order->has_status( 'shipped' ) ) {
        $email_key   = 'WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'; // The email notification type
        $email_obj   = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()[$email_key]; // Get specific WC_emails object
        $heading_txt = sprintf( __('Order #%s has been Shipped!', 'woocommerce'), '{order_number}' ); // New subject text
        return $email_obj->format_string( $heading_txt );
    }
    return $heading;
}
// Customize email subject for this custom status email notification
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_customer_processing_order', 'email_subject_customer_shipped_order', 10, 2 );
function email_subject_customer_shipped_order( $subject, $order ){
    if( $order->has_status( 'shipped' ) ) {
        $email_key   = 'WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'; // The email notification type
        $email_obj   = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()[$email_key]; // Get specific WC_emails object
        $subject_txt = sprintf( __('Your %s Order #%s has been Shipped!', 'woocommerce'), '{site_title}', '{order_number}' ); // New subject text
        return $email_obj->format_string( $subject_txt );
    }
    return $subject;
}
```

**ATTEMPTED/NOT WORKING - Email notification for BOTH custom statuses**

```
// Adding action for 'awaiting-delivery'
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'custom_email_actions', 20, 1 );
function custom_email_actions( $action ) {
  $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-shipped';
  $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-readytocollect';
  return $actions;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-shipped', array( WC(), 'send_transactional_email' ), 10, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-readytocollect', array( WC(), 'send_transactional_email' ), 10, 1 );

// Sending an email notification when order gets a custom status
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'custom_status_trigger_email_notification', 10, 4);
function custom_status_trigger_email_notification( $order_id, $from_status, $to_status, $order ) {
   $custom_statuses = array('Shipped', 'Ready to Collect'); // Here your custom statuses slugs

   if( in_array($to_status, $custom_statuses) ) {
       // Loop through each custom status
       foreach ( $custom_statuses as $custom_status ) {
           // Trigger an email notification when a order get a custom status
           if ( $custom_status === $to_status ) {
               WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
           }
       }
   }
}

// Customize email heading for your custom statuses email notifications
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_heading_customer_processing_order', 'custom_email_heading_for_custom_order_status', 10, 2 );
function custom_email_heading_for_custom_order_status( $heading, $order ){
   // Here your custom statuses slugs / Heading texts pairs
   $custom_statuses = array(
       'Shipped'         => __('Planet Vape {order_number} has been Shipped!','woocommerce'),
       'Ready to Collect' => __('Planet Vape {order_number} is Ready to Collect!','woocommerce')
   );

   // Loop through each custom status / heading text pairs
   foreach ( $custom_statuses as $custom_status => $heading_text ) {
       // Change an email notification heading text when a order get a custom status
       if( $order->has_status( $custom_status ) ) {
           $email = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']; // Get the specific WC_emails object

           return $email->format_string( $heading_text );
       }
   }
   return $heading;
}

// Customize email subject for your custom statuses email notifications
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_customer_processing_order', 'custom_email_subject_for_custom_order_status', 10, 2 );
function custom_email_subject_for_custom_order_status( $subject, $order ){
   // Here your custom statuses slugs / Heading texts pairs
   $custom_statuses = array(
       'Shipped'         => __('Planet Vape {order_number} has been Shipped!','woocommerce'),
       'Ready to Collect' => __('Planet Vape {order_number} is Ready to Collect!','woocommerce')
   );

   // Loop through each custom status / subject text pairs
   foreach ( $custom_statuses as $custom_status => $subject_text ) {
       // Change an email notification heading text when a order get a custom status
       if( $order->has_status( $custom_status ) ) {
           $email = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']; // Get the specific WC_emails object

           return $email->format_string( $subject_text );
       }
   }
   return $subject;
}
```

**FULL CODE WITH WORKING MAIL FOR SINGLE CUSTOM STATUS.**
This shows my full process of adding custom statuses with bulk actions and action buttons - All working fine.

```
add_action('init', 'register_custom_order_statuses');
function register_custom_order_statuses() {
    register_post_status('wc-shipped ', array(
        'label' => __( 'Shipped', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count' => _n_noop('Shipped <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Shipped <span class="count">(%s)</span>')
    ));
    register_post_status('wc-readytocollect ', array(
        'label' => __( 'Ready to Collect', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count' => _n_noop('Ready to Collect <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Ready to Collect <span class="count">(%s)</span>')
    ));
}


// Add a custom order status to list of WC Order statuses
add_filter('wc_order_statuses', 'add_custom_order_statuses');
function add_custom_order_statuses($order_statuses) {
    $new_order_statuses = array();

    // add new order status before processing
    foreach ($order_statuses as $key => $status) {
        $new_order_statuses[$key] = $status;
        if ('wc-processing' === $key) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-shipped'] = __('Shipped', 'woocommerce' );
            $new_order_statuses['wc-readytocollect'] = __('Ready to Collect', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }
    return $new_order_statuses;
}


// Adding custom status 'awaiting-delivery' to admin order list bulk dropdown
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order', 50, 1 );
function custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order( $actions ) {
    $new_actions = array();

    // add new order status before processing
    foreach ($actions as $key => $action) {
        if ('mark_processing' === $key)
            $new_actions['mark_shipped'] = __( 'Change status to shipped', 'woocommerce' );
            $new_actions['mark_readytocollect'] = __( 'Change status to Ready to Collect', 'woocommerce' );
            
        $new_actions[$key] = $action;
    }
    return $new_actions;
}

// Add a custom order status action button (for orders with "processing" status)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', 'add_custom_order_status_actions_button', 100, 2 );
function add_custom_order_status_actions_button( $actions, $order ) {
    // Display the button for all orders that have a 'processing', 'pending' or 'on-hold' status
    if ( $order->has_status( array( 'on-hold', 'processing', 'pending' ) ) ) {

        // The key slug defined for your action button
        $action_slug = 'shipped';

        // Set the action button
        $actions[$action_slug] = array(
            'url'       => wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce_mark_order_status&status='.$action_slug.'&order_id='.$order->get_id() ), 'woocommerce-mark-order-status' ),
            'name'      => __( 'Shipped', 'woocommerce' ),
            'action'    => $action_slug,
        );
    }
    return $actions;
}

// Set styling for custom order status action button icon and List icon
add_action( 'admin_head', 'add_custom_order_status_actions_button_css' );
function add_custom_order_status_actions_button_css() {
    $action_slug = "shipped"; // The key slug defined for your action button
    ?>
    <style>
        .wc-action-button-<?php echo $action_slug; ?>::after {
            font-family: woocommerce !important; content: "\e029" !important;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'filter_woocommerce_email_actions' );
function filter_woocommerce_email_actions( $actions ){
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-shipped';
    return $actions;
}

// Send Customer Processing Order email notification when order status get changed from "tree" to "processing"
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'shipped_status_custom_notification', 10, 4);
function shipped_status_custom_notification( $order_id, $from_status, $to_status, $order ) {
    if(  'shipped' === $to_status ) {
        // The email notification type
        $email_key   = 'WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order';

        // Get specific WC_emails object
        $email_obj = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()[$email_key];

        // Sending the customized email
        $email_obj->trigger( $order_id );
    }
}

// Customize email heading for this custom status email notification
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_heading_customer_processing_order', 'email_heading_customer_shipped_order', 10, 2 );
function email_heading_customer_shipped_order( $heading, $order ){
    if( $order->has_status( 'shipped' ) ) {
        $email_key   = 'WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'; // The email notification type
        $email_obj   = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()[$email_key]; // Get specific WC_emails object
        $heading_txt = sprintf( __('Order #%s has been Shipped!', 'woocommerce'), '{order_number}' ); // New subject text

        return $email_obj->format_string( $heading_txt );
    }
    return $heading;
}

// Customize email subject for this custom status email notification
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_customer_processing_order', 'email_subject_customer_shipped_order', 10, 2 );
function email_subject_customer_shipped_order( $subject, $order ){
    if( $order->has_status( 'shipped' ) ) {
        $email_key   = 'WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order'; // The email notification type
        $email_obj   = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()[$email_key]; // Get specific WC_emails object
        $subject_txt = sprintf( __('Your %s Order #%s has been Shipped!', 'woocommerce'), '{site_title}', '{order_number}' ); // New subject text

        return $email_obj->format_string( $subject_txt );
    }
    return $subject;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some mistakes… For multiple order statuses with custom email notifications use the following complete code *(removing before all your related code)*:

```
// Enable custom statuses for WooCommerce Orders
add_action('init', 'register_custom_order_statuses');
function register_custom_order_statuses() {

    register_post_status('wc-shipped ', array(
        'label' => __( 'Shipped', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count' => _n_noop('Shipped <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Shipped <span class="count">(%s)</span>')
    ));

    register_post_status('wc-readytocollect ', array(
        'label' => __( 'Ready to Collect', 'woocommerce' ),
        'public' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'show_in_admin_all_list' => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count' => _n_noop('Ready to Collect <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Ready to Collect <span class="count">(%s)</span>')
    ));
}

// Add a custom order status to list of WC Order statuses
add_filter('wc_order_statuses', 'add_custom_order_statuses');
function add_custom_order_statuses($order_statuses) {
    $new_order_statuses = array();

    // add new order status before processing
    foreach ($order_statuses as $key => $status) {
        $new_order_statuses[$key] = $status;
        if ('wc-processing' === $key) {
            $new_order_statuses['wc-shipped'] = __('Shipped', 'woocommerce' );
            $new_order_statuses['wc-readytocollect'] = __('Ready to Collect', 'woocommerce' );
        }
    }
    return $new_order_statuses;
}

// Adding custom status statuses to admin order list bulk dropdown
add_filter( 'bulk_actions-edit-shop_order', 'custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order', 50, 1 );
function custom_dropdown_bulk_actions_shop_order( $actions ) {
    $new_actions = array();

    // add new order status before processing
    foreach ($actions as $key => $action) {
        if ('mark_processing' === $key) {
            $new_actions['mark_shipped'] = __( 'Change status to shipped', 'woocommerce' );
            $new_actions['mark_readytocollect'] = __( 'Change status to Ready to Collect', 'woocommerce' );
        }
        $new_actions[$key] = $action;
    }
    return $new_actions;
}

// Add a custom order statuses action button (for orders with "processing" status)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_actions', 'add_custom_order_status_actions_button', 100, 2 );
function add_custom_order_status_actions_button( $actions, $order ) {
    $allowed_statuses = array( 'on-hold', 'processing', 'pending', 'shipped', 'readytocollect' ); // Define allowed statuses

    // Display the button for all orders that have allowed status (as defined in the array)
    if ( in_array( $order->get_status(), $allowed_statuses ) ) {

        // The key slug defined from status with the name
        $action_slugs = array(
            'shipped'        => __('Shipped', 'woocommerce'),
            'readytocollect' => __('Ready to Collect', 'woocommerce')
        );

        // Loop through custom statuses
        foreach ( $action_slugs as $action_slug => $name ) {
            // Display "processing" action button
            $actions['processing'] = array(
                'url'    => wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce_mark_order_status&status=processing&order_id=' . $order->get_id() ), 'woocommerce-mark-order-status' ),
                'name'   => __( 'Processing', 'woocommerce' ),
                'action' => 'processing',
            );

            // Display "complete" action button
            $actions['complete'] = array(
                'url'    => wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce_mark_order_status&status=completed&order_id=' . $order->get_id() ), 'woocommerce-mark-order-status' ),
                'name'   => __( 'Complete', 'woocommerce' ),
                'action' => 'complete',
            );

            // Display custom status action buttons
            if( $order->get_status() !== $action_slug ) {
                // Set the action button
                $actions[$action_slug] = array(
                    'url'       => wp_nonce_url( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=woocommerce_mark_order_status&status='.$action_slug.'&order_id='.$order->get_id() ), 'woocommerce-mark-order-status' ),
                    'name'      => $name,
                    'action'    => $action_slug,
                );
            }
        }
    }
    return $actions;
}

// Set styling for custom order status action button icon and List icon
add_action( 'admin_head', 'add_custom_order_status_actions_button_css' );
function add_custom_order_status_actions_button_css() {
    // The key slug defined from status with the icon code
    $action_slugs = array(
        'shipped'        => '\e019',
        'readytocollect' => '\e029'
    );
    ?>
    <style>
    <?php foreach ( $action_slugs as $action_slug => $icon_code ) : ?>
        .wc-action-button-<?php echo $action_slug; ?>::after {
            font-family: woocommerce !important; content: "<?php echo $icon_code; ?>" !important;
        }
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </style>
    <?php
}

// Adding action for custom statuses
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'custom_email_actions', 20, 1 );
function custom_email_actions( $action ) {
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-shipped';
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-readytocollect';

    return $actions;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-shipped', array( 'WC_Emails', 'send_transactional_email' ), 10, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-readytocollect', array( 'WC_Emails', 'send_transactional_email' ), 10, 1 );


// Sending an email notification when order get a custom status
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_shipped', 'cutom_status_trigger_email_notification', 10, 2 );
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_readytocollect', 'cutom_status_trigger_email_notification', 10, 2 );
function cutom_status_trigger_email_notification( $order_id, $order ) {
    WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
}

// Customize email heading for your custom statuses email notifications
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_heading_customer_processing_order', 'custom_email_heading_for_custom_order_status', 10, 2 );
function custom_email_heading_for_custom_order_status( $heading, $order ){
    // Here your custom statuses slugs / Heading texts pairs
    $data = array(
        'shipped'        => __('Planet Vape {order_number} has been Shipped!','woocommerce'),
        'readytocollect' => __('Planet Vape {order_number} is Ready to Collect!','woocommerce')
    );

    // Loop through each custom status / heading text pairs
    foreach ( $data as $custom_status => $heading_text ) {
        // Change an email notification heading text when a order get a custom status
        if( $order->has_status( $custom_status ) ) {
           $email = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']; // Get the specific WC_emails object

           $heading = $email->format_string( $heading_text ); // don't return directly
        }
    }
    return $heading;
}

// Customize email subject for your custom statuses email notifications
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_subject_customer_processing_order', 'custom_email_subject_for_custom_order_status', 10, 2 );
function custom_email_subject_for_custom_order_status( $subject, $order ){
    // Here your custom statuses slugs / Heading texts pairs
    $data = array(
        'shipped'        => __('Planet Vape {order_number} has been Shipped!','woocommerce'),
        'readytocollect' => __('Planet Vape {order_number} is Ready to Collect!','woocommerce')
    );

    // Loop through each custom status / subject text pairs
    foreach ( $data as $custom_status => $subject_text ) {
        // Change an email notification heading text when a order get a custom status
        if( $order->has_status( $custom_status ) ) {
            $email = WC()->mailer()->get_emails()['WC_Email_Customer_Processing_Order']; // Get the specific WC_emails object

            $subject = $email->format_string( $subject_text ); // don't return directly
        }
    }
    return $subject;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.